# Merge Replication First Snapshot don't work

Tags: sql-server, replication, snapshot, merge-replication

When doing the First Synchronization in Merge Replication, I'm having this error:

**"Cannot delete table 'dbo.eqp_Equipment' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 4712)"**

Then I changed the "Action if name is in use" to "Truncate all data in the existing object", then I had the same issue:

**"Cannot truncate table 'dbo.eqp_Equipment' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 4712)"**

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge replication does not guarantee transactional consistency, nor do they guarantee changes are applied in the order it was received. ie on a subscriber, a child table could be updated before the parent.  You have a couple options:

1. Mark the foreign keys on the subscriber "NOT FOR REPLICATION". This tells SQL Server to ignore FK constraints for Replication.
2. Specify a [processing order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147310.aspx) for the merge articles